# Problem writing a file from a Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight

Look at the following code (it's a part of Silverlight app):

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "JSON Files|*.json|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
dialog.DefaultExt = "json";
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
    string filename = dialog.SafeFileName;
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = 
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Create));
    sw.Write("string");
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}
```

It works (creates file and writes "string" there) on the developer machine, but does nothing on my machine, the file isn't created at all.

Any ideas what it can be?! Thank you in advance!

P.S. We tried removing the `sw.Flush();` and that did not help. Also we tried to set autoflush to true - didn't help as well. Changing `FileMode.Create` to `FileMode.Append` has no effect too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a security problem, you need to use the filestream that is returned by the SaveFileDialog. Use it to open the stream and write.

[SaveFileDialog.OpenFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: hm, and why then that's all OK on developer machine?

Comment: @Eugeny89 because you own the process. You are debugging using the cassini built-in webserver. If you publish it to IIS on your local machine, it will stop working.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as you're correct, they are in different namespaces, you've linked to the windows forms namespace in your answer which threw me off the scent.

Comment: @BenCr Sorry for the confusion. I have now switched the link to point to the one with the Silverlight example to make sure it won't happen again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "JSON Files|*.json|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        dialog.DefaultExt = "json";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(( Stream )dialog.OpenFile());
            sw.Write("string");
            sw.Close();
        }
```